# Select column values with max value between two columns

Tags: r

I have a dataframe called

```
tt <- structure(list(IID1 = c("035-0028-0151526", "036-1002-0282844", 
"950-0001-0081329", "951-1000-0084436", "954-0009-0337439", "954-0011-0379455", 
"955-0017-0354237", "6011039", "6011039", "6011039", "6011039", 
"6205526", "A1858", "A2159"), IID2 = c("035-0028-0157134", "036-1002-0305628", 
"950-0001-0100509", "951-1000-0084537", "954-0009-0337641", "954-0011-0379657", 
"955-0017-0363137", "6205526", "6215777", "A1864", "A2267", "A1864", 
"A1864", "A2267"), nIID1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
1, 1, 1), nIID2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2)), row.names = c(NA, 
-14L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x38b6d80>)
```

I want to extract values from `IID1` and `IID2` and put in column `selected`. If `nIID1 == nIID2`, I want values from `IID1`, otherwise, I want value from column with max IID. For example, if nIID1 has a higher value than nIID2, then I want a value from IID1.  Can someone guide me with the solution? Thanks!

The result should look like below.

```
               IID1             IID2 nIID1 nIID2         selected
 1: 035-0028-0151526 035-0028-0157134     1     1 035-0028-0151526
 2: 036-1002-0282844 036-1002-0305628     1     1 036-1002-0282844
 3: 950-0001-0081329 950-0001-0100509     1     1 950-0001-0081329
 4: 951-1000-0084436 951-1000-0084537     1     1 951-1000-0084436
 5: 954-0009-0337439 954-0009-0337641     1     1 954-0009-0337439
 6: 954-0011-0379455 954-0011-0379657     1     1 954-0011-0379455
 7: 955-0017-0354237 955-0017-0363137     1     1 955-0017-0354237
 8:          6011039          6205526     4     1          6011039
 9:          6011039          6215777     4     1          6011039
10:          6011039            A1864     4     3          6011039
11:          6011039            A2267     4     2          6011039
12:          6205526            A1864     1     3            A1864
13:            A1858            A1864     1     3            A1864
14:            A2159            A2267     1     2            A2267
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may get the column index with `max.col`, `cbind` with the row index (`.I`), extract the corresponding values from the `cbind`ed IID1, IID2 and assign (`:=`) to 'selected'

```
tt[, selected := cbind(IID1, IID2)[cbind(.I, max.col(.SD, "first"))],
      .SDcols = nIID1:nIID2]
```

-output

```
> tt
                IID1             IID2 nIID1 nIID2         selected
 1: 035-0028-0151526 035-0028-0157134     1     1 035-0028-0151526
 2: 036-1002-0282844 036-1002-0305628     1     1 036-1002-0282844
 3: 950-0001-0081329 950-0001-0100509     1     1 950-0001-0081329
 4: 951-1000-0084436 951-1000-0084537     1     1 951-1000-0084436
 5: 954-0009-0337439 954-0009-0337641     1     1 954-0009-0337439
 6: 954-0011-0379455 954-0011-0379657     1     1 954-0011-0379455
 7: 955-0017-0354237 955-0017-0363137     1     1 955-0017-0354237
 8:          6011039          6205526     4     1          6011039
 9:          6011039          6215777     4     1          6011039
10:          6011039            A1864     4     3          6011039
11:          6011039            A2267     4     2          6011039
12:          6205526            A1864     1     3            A1864
13:            A1858            A1864     1     3            A1864
14:            A2159            A2267     1     2            A2267
```

---

Or another option is `fcase`

```
tt[, selected := fcase(nIID1 >= nIID2, IID1, nIID1 < nIID2, IID2)]
```

EDIT: as suggested by @Marco_CH

Answer (score 2):

In data.table you can do this with an oneliner.

**Update 21:02, even shorter:**

```
setDT(tt)
tt[, selected:=ifelse(nIID1 >= nIID2, IID1, IID2)]
```

**Output (Updated, thanks to akrun):**

```
> tt                                    
                IID1             IID2 nIID1 nIID2         selected
 1: 035-0028-0151526 035-0028-0157134     1     1 035-0028-0151526
 2: 036-1002-0282844 036-1002-0305628     1     1 036-1002-0282844
 3: 950-0001-0081329 950-0001-0100509     1     1 950-0001-0081329
 4: 951-1000-0084436 951-1000-0084537     1     1 951-1000-0084436
 5: 954-0009-0337439 954-0009-0337641     1     1 954-0009-0337439
 6: 954-0011-0379455 954-0011-0379657     1     1 954-0011-0379455
 7: 955-0017-0354237 955-0017-0363137     1     1 955-0017-0354237
 8:          6011039          6205526     4     1          6011039
 9:          6011039          6215777     4     1          6011039
10:          6011039            A1864     4     3          6011039
11:          6011039            A2267     4     2          6011039
12:          6205526            A1864     1     3            A1864
13:            A1858            A1864     1     3            A1864
14:            A2159            A2267     1     2            A2267
```